# Duplicate record detail and record in the same page of report

Tags: ms-access, report

Is there a way I could repeat the same report detail and the record repeatedly for one page or more? I had conditionally displayed images in the print event in the detail. I'm currently creating some labels for chemicals. Is it possible? Any hints anddirection are welcome.

The design of the label:

[image]

Comment: Repeat repeatedly. That's many times. And what's the difference between record and record detail?

Comment: Have a look at the Print event of the details section and on the NextRecord property of the report.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the following three report properties, especially `NextRecord`.  You'll need to set these in the Detail section's `OnPrint` event:

> `MoveLayout`: if False, prints on top of what was printed last;
>     `NextRecord`: if False, prints the same record again;
>     `PrintSection`: if False, doesn't print any data.

Source: [Allen Browne](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-12.html)